# Scala Linq alternative

Tags: c#, linq, scala

I'm trying to re-write an application from .net to Scala, mainly for practice and I've come across this Linq expression that I don't know how to work with.  linq is also foreign to me so I'm a little bit out of my depth.

```
private void DeleteItems(AmazonSimpleDB client, IEnumerable<string> itemNames) 
{
    var deleteableItems = from n in itemNames select new DeleteableItem() 
    {
        ItemName = n
    }
}
```

I'm looking at some other answers using maps but so far have been unsuccessful, thank you for any help.

Comment: What exactly is your question? The code you show creates a `IEnumerable<DeletableItem>` (`deletableItems`): for each string in `itemNames` an instance of `DeleteableItem` is created and its property `ItemName` is set to that string (if this is the full code of the method, the method seems useless as this sequence is not used anywhere).

Comment: It would be easier to help if you have a specific problem.

Comment: @RenéVogt, apologies, I thought the snippet would be enough as the rest of the code passes this to a request whereby it's then deleted.

Comment: You know this snippet actually does nothing, right? You never *materliaze* the `IEnumerable<T>`, which is lazy in C#

Answer (score 2):

It will look something like this:

```
var deleteableItems = itemNames.map(n -> new DeleteableItem(ItemName = n))
```

Note that your `DeleteableItem` should have constructor with `ItemName` parameter.

Comment: thank you Talex, as soon as IntelliJ restarts I'll try and mark the answer. :)

Comment: Yeah, if you translate from LINQ to functional programming, `Select == map`, `SelectMany == flatMap`, `Where == filter`. Weird terminology, I have to say.